# Is it possible to make a script that runs commands on Console 2?

Tags: console2

I use Win XP.
I have no admin rights on this computer, so I'm not allowed to access the System variables. I can run a batch file, but it annoys me that both cmd and Console 2 are then running.
I would like Console 2 to be run exclusively.

Here's what's in my batch file:

```
set JAVA_HOME=D:\apps\jdk1.6.17
"D:\Program Files\Console2\Console.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need some external **shell process** to run into Console 2, let it be cmd.exe or something like bash. That said, if you are doing things right you will have just one **terminal window** running: in this case, Console2.

Please clarify what you really need to do in your batch file (I suppose running some Java program, since you set JAVA_HOME): you should run the batch from inside Console, not the opposite.